# GetRoomLists succeeds but returns no data

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices

I am calling GetRoomLists using Exchange Web Services, we are running Exchange 2010. The below code is being executed through a Console application. The call succeeds, per the XML response of "No Error", but no data is returned.  We have several hundred rooms listed when you try to add one through an Outlook Appointment, so not sure why this would happen.

I've tried using both EWS DLL version 1.2 and 2.0, using default credentials or passing in credentials. I noticed after originally posting this that the response header says we are using Exchange 2012 SP2, so I tried updating my code to use that ExchangeVersion enum value, but no change in the result.

I have successfully used EWS on this Exchange server to read mailboxes, but never rooms before.

**C#**

```
        ExchangeService es = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        es.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.EwsResponse | TraceFlags.EwsRequest;
        es.TraceEnabled = true;
        es.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        es.AutodiscoverUrl("autodiscover@example.com");
        //this collection is empty after processing
        EmailAddressCollection eac = es.GetRoomLists();
```

**XML Trace From Web Service Request/Response**

```
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="9" Time="2013-03-13 20:39:41Z" Version="14.03.0032.000">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:GetRoomLists />
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>

<Trace Tag="EwsResponse" Tid="9" Time="2013-03-13 20:39:41Z" Version="14.03.0032.000">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
      <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="2" MajorBuildNumber="328" MinorBuildNumber="9" Version="Exchange2010_SP2" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <GetRoomListsResponse ResponseClass="Success" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
        <ResponseCode>NoError</ResponseCode>
        <m:RoomLists xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" />
      </GetRoomListsResponse>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
</Trace>
```

MSDN Documentation on GetRoomLists: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd899416(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Have you tried using different accounts? Maybe the calling identity doesn't have permission to see any room lists? In which case the server would just return the empty list, as seen in your trace. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd899416(v=exchg.140).aspx lists your response as typical for not having any room lists on the server.

Comment: @RomanGruber - Having just read up a bit more on what a Room List actually is, how can I get a list of rooms in exchange like Outlook does without a room list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I found the cause/solution.  The confusion was in that GetRoomLists does not return a list of rooms, but instead a list of a list of rooms, or a collection of "Room Lists".  These are a special type of distribution list that contains a list of rooms.

As outlined here, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/4ff04c60-48c2-4a69-ab75-2383e73bfde2, you either need to setup room lists or you need to query AD and check the msExchRecipientDisplayType attribute to track down the rooms.

This link shows an example of how to write the LDAP query to return rooms: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/e2d10953-a8f9-459c-8a0e-f10c2e568b26

Code I put together for finding rooms:

```
private List<string> GetConfRooms(string filter)
{
    List<string> sRooms = new List<string>();

    DirectoryEntry deDomain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain().GetDirectoryEntry();
    DirectorySearcher dsRooms = new DirectorySearcher(deDomain);

    dsRooms.Filter = string.Format("(&(&(&(mailNickname={0}*)(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user)(msExchRecipientDisplayType=7))))", filter);

    dsRooms.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
    dsRooms.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

    foreach (SearchResult sr in dsRooms.FindAll())
    {
        sRooms.Add(sr.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
    }

    return sRooms;
}
```

Comment: @user301639 - The LDAP query from the second link in my answer does bring back the rooms from AD, so it looks like it's working.

Comment: I got lost with the code, there is some deadlock with the steps order, 

string roRootDSE = dsDirectorySearcher.SearchRoot.Path;


        DirectoryEntry deDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(roRootDSE);
        DirectorySearcher dsDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(deDirectoryEntry);

how did you solve it ?

thanks!

Comment: @user301639 - I didn't run into anything unusual.  I've posted the code, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Peter, Thanks for help, and what exactly the filter you sending is ? Thanks

Comment: @Igal - You don't have to provide a filter at all for this to work, but where I work our conference rooms use a naming convention of Site-Building-Room, the filter is so you can pass in a formatted string to limit the results. For testing purposes try String.Empty as your filter and see what comes back.

Comment: Great, Worked :) I just removed the string.format and sent is a query and it's working Thanks !