# VSTO Identify shared vs User mailbox

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins, comaddin

In a VSTO add-in, I am trying to retrieve if the type of the mailbox is shared, user or resource.
I read some interesting posts related to the question and try to look at the OlExchangeStoreType or GetConversation or MailboxType but did not succeed.
I have seen the solution (3) from @DmitryStreblechenko but I would prefer to not use EWS if possible.
It seems that the value that I am looking for is the [msExchRecipientTypeDetails](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/recipient-type-values/7c2620e5-9870-48ba-b5c2-7772c739c651).
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Relevant articles

1. [EWS Get mailbox type (user/resource/shared)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427308/ews-get-mailbox-type-user-resource-shared)
2. [MailItem.GetConversation() on shared mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750740/mailitem-getconversation-on-shared-mailbox)
3. [In Outlook Addin, how do I determine if an email's Sender is a shared mailbox email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785831/in-outlook-addin-how-do-i-determine-if-an-emails-sender-is-a-shared-mailbox-em?rq=1)
4. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1088741/How-to-list-subfolders-in-inbox-folder-in-shared-e
5. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/612248/in-outlook-addin-how-do-i-determine-that-an-email.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, VSTO doesn't provide anything for that.

Second, the Outlook object model doesn't differentiate shared/local stores. So, you will not find any property or method for that in the OOM. The best what you could do is to use the [Store.ExchangeStoreType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.exchangestoretype) property which returns a constant in the [OlExchangeStoreType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olexchangestoretype) enumeration that indicates the type of an Exchange store.

It is up to you which way/workaround is to use form the list shared above.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I don't see how the OlExchangeStoreType can help. Shared and user mailboxes return olPrimaryExchangeMailbox. Did you think of something in particular?

Comment: That is definitely not a solution. As a I wrote, the OOM doesn't provide anything for that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use EWS - try to read `Namespace.AutoDiscoverXml` property to check if the shared mailbox and its type are there - you can see it in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author): click Namespace button, select AutoDiscoverXml property.

Look for the `AlternativeMailbox\Type` nodes - you can have "Archive", "Delegate", "TeamMailbox".

Comment: Hello Dimitry, nice to hear from you as always! Yes, I noticed the solution provided under link 3 but unfortunately I am not dealing with a mail but with an appointment item. I am not sure if it is related but the autodiscover property of the appointment does not include the alternative AlternativeMailbox\Type. I have tried with app.Session.AutoDiscoverXml or app.Parent.Session.AutoDiscoverXml.

Comment: Yes Autodiscover is specific to a particular Exchange account, I am not sure how it relates to a particular appointment. Do you mean you are trying to find out what the parent mailbox/store is?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the case of my add-in, I only have an appointment item which is being open by the user. I am trying to understand if the appointment (app) is from the user calendar or from shared calendar. I have try the autodiscover on "app.GetOrganizer().GetExchangeUser().Session.Accounts", " app.Session.Accounts" or "app.Parent.Session.Accounts" but none of those get me an AutoDiscoverXML with the AlternativeMailbox node. The mailbox is a M365 mailbox.

Comment: What do you see for that mailbox in Namespace.AutoDiscoverXml?