# How can I get a list of rooms from O365?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

I want to get all rooms/ressources from Office365.
I didn't find a way to get the rooms via o365 Api.

As I looked to other stackoverflow questions, the Office EWS seem to be the only way to get the rooms.
I tried it, but I don't get any result...

Any ideas why? Is there maybe another way to get the rooms?

Here my code:

```
        var y = await this.getAccessToken();
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        service.HttpHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.currentAccessToken);
        service.PreAuthenticate = true;
        service.SendClientLatencies = true;
        service.EnableScpLookup = false;
        service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        EmailAddressCollection myRoomLists = service.GetRoomLists();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetRoomLists succeeds but returns no data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396073/getroomlists-succeeds-but-returns-no-data)